# Opensource like Camtasia Studio

Tags: youtube, video-editing, camtasia

i used to create a tutorial video with camtasia studio, but curious to know if opensource have application that provide abilities like camtasia studio have
   such as
      - keep track action happen during recording. can produce video that zoom to part i want.
      - Display the text of screencast as an overlay or below the video.
      - With just one click, video is on its way to YouTube .

Comment: I would love to find out that there's something like this available!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching a bit online, here's what I come up with: http://camstudio.org/

It can create video recordings off your screen, and generate swf's to easily inject them into websites.
It's able to add nice, anti-aliased screen captions to the video, and even supports picture-in-picture video (screen caption + video of you through the webcam)
You can record the whole screen, or just a portion of it.. I'm not sure if it supports zooming-in to sub areas while live recoding, but even if it doesn't - it's easy to emulate this using Windows 7 zoom (or if you don't use Win7 with tools like [ZoomIt](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897434.aspx) from Sysinternals
It comes with it's own free codec as well.

It's all 100% free, open source and licensed under GPL, woo!! :D

P.S. I'm in no way affiliated with them.. I just found it myself :)